# Lua string comparison not working

Tags: string, lua, string-comparison

Well I am learning Lua at the moment and I wanted to write a little script.
It's just for practice and understanding how Lua is working.

```
   local name = io.read()

 if name == Test
  then print("Right")
  else print("Wrong")
end
```

Normally the output should be "Right" if I enter "Test" but it always prints "Wrong". I tried it many times and wrote the code in other forms but didn't get my solution.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing a set of quotation marks.

This:

```
if name == Test
```

compares the values of two variables, `name` and `Test`.

You want this:

```
if name == "Test"
```

Lua doesn't require variables to be declared, so this is an easy mistake to make.

Comment: @Thorvason, could you mark this answer as correct, please (click the check mark to the left of it)?